# Generate script from SQL SERVER by java

Tags: java, sql-server, reverse-engineering

I need to generate a script to recreate a DB structure in a dev environment. I want to use java to make an app to automate this process.

I can get views and procedures from this query:

```
SELECT
    definition,
    uses_ansi_nulls,
    uses_quoted_identifier,
    is_schema_bound
FROM
    sys.sql_modules
```

But I need a all structure. I don't want to use SSMS, because it's a manual solution.

Comment: What do you mean automate ? Do you want a job to recreate the DB structure everyday ?

Comment: Something like that. I have a few apps, which DB, should be refreshed to DEV and TST env. But it's taking too long to do that manually. (we need that in every month)

Comment: if you are familiar with C# you can use "SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)". You can do almost everything you do with SSMS.

Comment: Aside from C#, [`sqlpackage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/tools/sqlpackage) can be used to create a package that can be deployed later. SMO is a bit of a dragon.